# Wake up the system without having to enter a user password on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, 20.04, kde, password, auto-login

I am running Kubuntu 20.04 and I don't want to have to use a user password. I am the only user. How can I avoid having to write my user password each time I wake my laptop from sleep?

I tried many commands on `sudo` and it still doesn't work!!

Answer (score 2):

Get to `system settings> Workspace Behaviour (under Workspace)> Screen Locking> uncheck 'Lockscreen: After waking from sleep'`
You can also adjust time of inactivity after which screen to lock. If you don't your screen not locked at all uncheck `Lockscreen: Automatically after`.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `system > administration > login`(or similar location and may from Ubuntu version ) and select your username and check to login automatically.

[image: screen]

If you also don't want to lock it for inactivity, uncheck ***lock screen when screensaver is active***

---- Or -----

You can run the command
`sudo visudo`
Find the line with your username, and change it to the following:

```
$yourname ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Answer (score 1):

Only clarifying for Kubuntu. Here are the pics for Kubuntu. Workspace behaviour screen locking.

[image]

And you can set to login automatically when you turn on as well. from User Management.
[image]

Comment: Doing  it via screen locking doesn't help if you're logging out and logging in again.